# 'InlineResponse2002' object is not subscriptable | How do I manipulate the API response?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, object, giphy-api

Code:

```
import time
import giphy_client
from giphy_client.rest import ApiException
from pprint import pprint

def giphyapi():
    api_instance = giphy_client.DefaultApi()
    api_key = '################################'
    tag = 'test'
    rating = 'pg-13'
    fmt = 'json'

    try:
        # Search Endpoint
        api_response = api_instance.gifs_random_get(api_key, tag = tag, rating = rating, fmt = fmt)
        ## here’s where I want to do stuff with the data
    except ApiException as exc:
        print("Exception when calling DefaultApi->gifs_random_get: %s\n" % exc)
    return None

giphyapi()
```

Hi! How do I convert `api_instance` into something manipulatable, such as a dict?
This is the same problem as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49212062/python-inlineresponse200-object-is-not-subscriptable), but the solution that the question author found sadly did not work for me.

I have tried `print(api_response.data[0].images.type)`, but that threw this error:
*TypeError: 'RandomGif' object is not subscriptable*

I also tried this:

```
for block in api_response["data"]:
    giftype = block["type"]
```

But that threw this error:
*TypeError: 'InlineResponse2002' object is not subscriptable*

I’m using Python 3.8.1, and I’m also using [giphy-python-client](https://github.com/Giphy/giphy-python-client). [Here](https://github.com/Giphy/giphy-python-client/blob/master/docs/RandomGif.md) is a list of [RandomGif](https://github.com/Giphy/giphy-python-client/blob/master/docs/DefaultApi.md#gifs_random_get) models. The one I’m trying to fetch in the two examples of what I tried above is `type`.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it thanks to shoot2thr1ll284 on Reddit.

You just use `api_response.data.type` and replace `type` with the property that you want to fetch.